# Как работает оператор полнотекстового поиска FREETEXT в SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Разобрался над полнотекстовым поиском  при помощи предиката CONTAINS читая

http://djekmusic.blogspot.com/2012/03/ms-sql-2008-2.html

Но не разобрался над  интеллектуальным поиском FREETEXT..
Подскажите что это за механизм ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CONTAINS` находит только полные совпадения внутри колонок.

`FREETEXT` же берет язык колонки(или указанный аргументом `LANGUAGE`), и в соответствии с его правилами выполняет несколько действий, а именно:

1. Разбивает текст на отдельные слова
2. Удаляет из текста ненужный шум - междометия, суффиксы, предлоги, и т.д.
3. Дополняет текст основами слов(выполняет стемминг) - так скажем к слову "программистский" добавится "програмист".
4. Дополняет текст синонимами найденными в словарях.

Это делается как для поискового запроса, так и для содержимого колонок(правда т.к. эта операция довольно затратна, то для колонок она выполняется во время построения полнотекстового поиска, а вовсе не в момент запроса).

Слова из расширенного таким образом запроса и из полнотекстового индекса колонок сравниваются друг с другом.

Так-же подсчитывается релевантность совпадений - количество слов совпадающих с текстом запроса, качество совпадений(степень соответствия слов и фраз запроса с найденным в колонках текстом), и возможно другие факторы не описанные Microsoft.

В качестве результата выдаются все найденные совпадения, отсортированные по ралевантности - от наиболее к наименее точным.

Примерно так-же работают поисковые системы.

---

Т.е. если у нас есть колонка таблицы, содержащая строки с несколькими фразами:

- Коты-Самураи
- Она и её кот
- Вперёд, девушка из книжного магазина!
- Барон - Кошачий Лорд

И есть поисковый запрос "Её кот", то `CONTAINS` вернет только один результат - "Она и её кот"

А вот `FREETEXT` выдаст все эти строки в примерно таком порядке:

1. Она и её кот
2. Барон - Кошачий Лорд
3. Коты-Самураи
4. Вперёд, девушка из книжного магазина!